# Mercurial HGEOL Best Practices

Tags: mercurial

What are the best practices today regarding dealing with line endings in mercurial? The [HGEOL extension wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EolExtension) page says it is a "feature of last resort" which tells me it should be avoided, however, I'm not aware of an alternative. If HGEOL extension is the best way to go then what are the best practices for configuring it?

Answer (score 1):

- "feature of last resort" **DOES NOT** mean "...should be avoided" - you have to improve your logic-skill, definitely (or language: "last resort" is more **"Ultima ratio regum"** than *"damned bullshit for loosers"*) - your own mileage may vary
- It's personal opinion of Mercurial developers - your own mileage may vary
- Instead of technical solution anybody can have and prefer administrative methods: in cross-platform environment 1) define 2) declare 3) control 4) enforce usage of uniform EOL-style by every developer on every workplace regardless of native default OS settings. I consider this solution as a managerial delirium (subject to human errors, not bullet-proof) and developers nightmare - your own mileage may vary

Comment: Wow, quite the hostile answer. Thanks for your opinion, I suppose, but I don't find it particularly useful.